# Use of std::forward for non-forwarding references

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am trying to figure out if my use of `std::forward` in the following code makes sense even though it is not a forwarding (=universal) reference. Please excuse the amount of code, but this is the stripped-down version of what I am trying to achieve.

```
template <class... Args>
class event_dispatcher {
private:
  using func_t = std::function<bool(Args...)>;

public: 
  bool operator()(Args... args) const {
    for (auto& f : funcs) {
      if (!f(args...))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  template <class F>
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<bool, F, Args...>>
  add(F&& f) {
    funcs.emplace_back(std::forward<F>(f));
  }

  template <class F>
  std::enable_if_t<!std::is_invocable_r_v<bool, F, Args...> && std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>>
  add(F&& f) {
    add([f_ = std::forward<F>(f)](Args... args){
         std::invoke(f_, std::forward<Args>(args)...); // <-- this is the one I am asking about!
         return true;
       });
  }

private:
  std::vector<func_t> funcs;
};
```

The idea is that if the callable passed to `add()` doesn't return a `bool`, we will wrap it in a lambda that does.

Now, if I just pass `args...` directly, it will always work, but if any of `Args` are rvalues then it will needlessly do a copy instead of a move. If I instead use `std::move(args)...` it will not work if any of `Args` is an lvalue. Using `std::forward<Args>(args)...` here seems to solve these problems and work as efficiently as possible in any case, but I am worried that I am missing something since I am using `std::forward` for a non-forwarding reference, and in general I am having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around the whole reference collapsing / rvalue reference / std::move / std::forward issues.

Comment: Looks ok for me.

Comment: I would suggest to read "Effective Modern C++" - Scott Meyers, chapter 5 "Rvalue Refrences, Move Semantics, and Perfect Forwarding"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::move` does not move `std::forward` does not forward.

`std::forward` is a *conditional move*.  `std::forward<T>` moves if `T` is a value or rvalue reference.

This lines up with when you want to move `args...`, so it is appropriate here.

A comment along those lines should be a good idea, as in any situation where you use `std::forward` outside of simple forwarding references.